# Custom log level issue in log4j2

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, customization, log4j2

Root logger is configured to be a synchronous logger at `INFO` level. I also have a couple of Async loggers. One of the Async logger is configured at a customized higher log level `TOAST` (789). This is higher than the `TRACE` level (600).

The reason for doing this is to have a log level that can be used for special events to be logged via Async logger and their own appenders.

We dont want the `TOAST` events to be going to the Synchronous Root loggers or other loggers.. but only to the Async `TOAST` logger and its corresponding appenders .. is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="120" packages=“com.pack.toast”>
     <CustomLevels>
        <CustomLevel name=“TOAST” intLevel=“789” />
    </CustomLevels>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/packiu.log"
            append="true" name="DRFILE"
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/packiu-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%t] %c %M - %p: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30" />
        </RollingFile>          
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/Users/toasty/logs/roll_file_app.log"
                     filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz" immediateFlush="true" >
               <PatternLayout>
                        <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
              </PatternLayout>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
        <Rewrite name="Rewrite" ignoreExceptions = "true"  >
            <ToastAppenderPolicy toastNeeded="true">
            </ToastAppenderPolicy>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Rewrite>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="net.rubyeye" level="off" />
        <Logger name="com.google.code" level="off" />               

        <AsyncLogger name="com.pack.toast.ToastLoggerImpl" level=“TOAST” includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="Rewrite" />
        </AsyncLogger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="DRFILE" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you really want a named logger not a custom level because you only ever want your messages to go to one logger and its appenders. Perhaps you should use something more like:

```
<AsyncLogger name="TOAST_LOGGER" level=“INFO” includeLocation="true">
    <AppenderRef ref="Rewrite" />
</AsyncLogger>
```

and then in your code

```
private static final Logger TOAST_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("TOAST_LOGGER");
...
TOAST_LOGGER.info("Toast message");
...
```

Otherwise, if you must use a custom log level then you can accomplish what you want by [filtering](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html) with a [Threshold Filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter).

Comment: Thanks for the Info @D.B. I did the named logger exactly as outlined but the log message still ends in both logger's output, Unfortunately.. (Synchronous Root and also with Asynchronous Named Logger) . Here is a sample of the output that goes to the SYNC logger - `2017-04-03 23:04:42,534 [http-nio-8443-exec-1] TOAST_LOGGER log - INFO: blah`. Any thoughts? I am fine without a custom log level, if this approach could be made to work. Thank you

Comment: I believe it's likely due to additivity. Please see the [additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) section of the log4j2 documentation and set additivity to false on the appropriate logger(s). I'm thinking setting it to false on the toast logger should be enough since it says, "Once an event reaches a logger with its additivity set to false the event will not be passed to any of its parent loggers, regardless of their additivity setting."

Comment: Thanks @D.B. additivity appears to have fixed the problem of the values getting relayed to the parent.